# JavaScript: Self-executing function with parameter

Tags: javascript, codemirror, self-executing-function

CodeMirror.net uses this construct (I'm simplifying slightly) to introduce the code for its JavaScript editor:

```
(function(mod) {
        this.CodeMirror = mod();
    })(function() {
      "use strict";
       (15,000-odd lines of advanced JS)
    }
```

Now, I understand that this is a self-executing function, and I've read a number of posts about them.  I understand that, in practice, this code is creating a CodeMirror object.  I just don't understand the mechanics.

1. What is the role of the parameter (mod)?  More broadly, what does it mean when you give a parameter to a self-executing function?
2. What is the role of the inner function() declaration?  It appears that this is related to mod in some way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The function is not self-executing. You are creating a function and then calling it immediately.

Comment: Yes, the term "self-executing function" is colloquially out of favor. The preferred term is "immediately-invoked function expression", or IIFE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code:

```
(function(mod) {
    this.CodeMirror = mod();
})(function() {
  "use strict";
   (15,000-odd lines of advanced JS)
}
```

`mod` is the formal parameter to the immediately-invoked function. It's as if the function were declared in a more straightforward way:

```
function something(mod) {
    this.CodeMirror = mod();
}
```

That function clearly expects that the `mod` parameter will be a reference to some *other* function, because the only thing it does is make a function call with it.

The immediately-invoked function is, in fact, called with a function as the value of the `mod` parameter: specifically, this one:

```
function() {
  "use strict";
   (15,000-odd lines of advanced JS)
}
```

That function does whatever it does, and (presumably) returns an object reference to be used as the global `CodeMirror` entry point.

Because the first function — the immediately-invoked one — is invoked without any explicit `this` value, it expects that `this` will be set to the value of the global context, or `window` in a browser. Personally I think it would be safer to do that explicitly:

```
(function(mod) {
    this.CodeMirror = mod();
}).call(this, function() {
  "use strict";
   (15,000-odd lines of advanced JS)
})
```

In the global lexical context, it *is* guaranteed that `this` will be a reference to the global context, "strict" mode or not. But if that outer immediately-invoked function is simply called, then `this` will be `undefined` in "strict" mode and the initialization would fail.

Comment: So, if I understand you, this would be equivalent to: window.CodeMirror =  function() { blah blah blah}    ...except that it's an immediately invoked function, which affects its scope.

Comment: I mean, window.CodeMirror = function() {blah blah blah}; window.CodeMirror();

Comment: @AngularNewbie no, it's like `window.CodeMirror = function() { blah }();` - the function has to be **called**, and the **result** of calling the function (the return value) is what becomes `window.CodeMirror`.

Comment: Oh!  I get it.  I think.  Because it says `this.CodeMirror = mod();` rather than `this.CodeMirror = mod;`  Trippy.  JavaScript just twangs my synapses!

Answer (score 2):

```
(function(mod) {
  this.CodeMirror = mod();
})(function() {
    "use strict";
    //(15,000-odd lines of advanced JS)
})
```

Nothing weird or magical is happening here, Here is the flow of this:

1. `(function(mod) {
     this.CodeMirror = mod();
   })` This declares an anonymous function and it accepts the parameter `mod`.
2. Then the line `this.CodeMirror = mod();` takes the `mod` and invoke it like a method, implying that programmer's expects mod to be a function. The **RETURN** value of that method is assigned to **Window.CodeMirror** object. Self invoking functions have their `this` set to `Window` Object.
3. Parenthesis right after anonymous function declaration invoke it, and in those parenthesis a function is passed a parameter.

Summary: The Result of function that has 15000 lines of code is assigned to `Window.CodeMirror`